# How to show that this vector subspace is closed?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $A=\{f\in L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]: f\equiv 0\textrm{ in } [-\pi,0]\}$ be a vector subspace in $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$. I want to show that this set is closed, but I am quite lost... I have tried to express the set $A$ as $S^{\perp}$ where $S$ is a subset of $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$ (as I know that $S^{\perp}$ is a closed vector subspace of $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$). Choosing $S=\{f\chi_{[-\pi,0]}: f\in L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]\}$ was my first option but I think I am mistaken. I don't even know if this is the right approach. Any hint/help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You can play with sequences.

Comment: Take a sequence in A that converges to an element in $L^2[-\pi , \pi]$ and show that the limit is an element in A.

Comment: So, I take $(f_{n})_{n}$ a sequence in $A$, that converges to a certain $g$ in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$; then, I just have to show that $g$ is in $A$; by hypothesis I would know that $f_{n}\equiv 0$ in $[-\pi,0]$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, and that the $f_{n}$ converge to $g$... But how can I work with this hypothesis that $g$ is in $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$? Thanks both for answering!

Comment: @rubikman23 The idea is to construct a subsequence of $f_n$, which converges pointwise almost everywhere. Usually something like this is proven together with the completeness theorem by Riesz-Fischer.

Comment: Am I missing something here? If $f,g$ are both zero in $[-\pi,0]$ then any linear combination of them is as well, right?

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes! That's it, and so that means that the set is a vector subspace, no?

Comment: @rubikman23 I think so, if $V$ is a vector space and $U\subseteq V$ is also a vector space, then $U$ is a subspace of $V$. I believe that is satisfied here